# Manipulate String to XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, string

I have extracted data from PDF which is in string format like below.(Please note on uneven spacing and new line characters).

```
 Virtual Salary                                 25,100.00   EIS EE Contr.                                       7.90
 Virtual Car Allowance                           1,600.00   EPF Employee Contr.                             2,937.00
 Payment Received(Oversea)                       4,265.01   SOCSO Employee Contr.                              19.75
```

How to convert this string to XML like below.

```
public void testMethod()
    {
        String extractedTestFromPDF=
                 " Virtual Salary                                 25,100.00   EIS EE Contr.                                       7.90\n"+
                 "\t Virtual Car Allowance                           1,600.00   EPF Employee Contr.                             2,937.00\n"+
                 " Payment Received(Oversea)                       4,265.01   SOCSO Employee Contr.                              19.75\n";

    }
```

Desire XML:

```
<xml>
<Data>
    <Allowance>Virtual Salary</Allowance>
    <Allowance_Amount>25,100.00</Allowance_Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Allowance>EIS EE Contr.</Allowance>
    <Allowance_Amount>7.90</Allowance_Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Allowance>Virtual Car Allowance</Allowance>
    <Allowance_Amount>1,600.00</Allowance_Amount>
</Data>
...
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String fixedSizetoXML(String extractedTestFromPDF) {
    String[] lines = extractedTestFromPDF.split("\\R");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(\\S.{20})\\s\\s+([-\\d,\\.]+)\\s+.*$");
    //                                      (--------)       (-----------)
    return "<?xml verion="1.0">\n<Xml>\n"
        + Stream.of(lines)
              .map(pattern::matcher)
              .filter(m::find)
              .map(m -> String.format("<Data>\n"
                            + "    <Allowance>%s</Allowance>\n"
                            + "    <Allowance_Amount>%s</Allowance_Amount>\n"
                            + "</Data>\n",
                            m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2)))

              .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
        + "<Xml>\n";
}
```

I took the liberty adding an XML preprocessing instruction `<?xml ...>` and for clarity changing `xml` to `Xml`.

These are records with fixed length fields. Counting positions is not entirely safe,
seeing a tab char `\t` and and considering special characters: `é` could be one char, but also `e` plus a special zero width `´`, I used a regex pattern instead. Requiring at least two whitespace chars before the amount.

---

***Java 7***

```
String fixedSizetoXML(String extractedTestFromPDF) {
    String[] lines = extractedTestFromPDF.split("\\R");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(\\S.{20})\\s\\s+([-\\d,\\.]+)\\s+.*$");
    //                                      (--------)       (-----------)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lines.length * 64);
    sb.append("<?xml verion="1.0">\n<Xml>\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            String data = String.format("<Data>\n"
                            + "    <Allowance>%s</Allowance>\n"
                            + "    <Allowance_Amount>%s</Allowance_Amount>\n"
                            + "</Data>\n",
                            m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2));
            sb.append(data);
        }
    }
    sb.append("<Xml>\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eggen. Appreciate if you could post the above method in java 7 as we still the use the old version.Sorry that I didn't mentioned.